# How to stop the execution of a bash command after N seconds?

Tags: bash

I am writing a simple bash script that analyses the contents of a directory and invokes a specific command for each file, however, in some cases, the execution takes longer than expected, and I would like to stop it after a certain number of seconds (or minutes) to move on to parsing the next entry.

For now, the script works in the following way:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /home/Users/Desktop/fdroid_tests/destination_dir/*; do
  if [ -d "$f" ]; then
     qark --java $f
  fi
done
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides just backgrounding the tasks, you may also be interested in the `timeout` command. For example `timeout 5s qark --java $f` will run your qark application and signal it to exit after 5 seconds if it hasn't already exited.

You can combine the two answers as well (`timeout 5s qark --java $f &`) if it's okay to have all your instances of qark run simultaneously. If you do, you may also want to add a `wait` after the loop so that the script doesn't exit until all the qark instances finish or timeout.

Answer (score 0):

In bash, it is possible to launch a process in background, using the ampersand switch:

```
qark --java $f &
```

You wait for five seconds:

```
sleep 5
```

You stop all running `qark` processes, using `pkill`:

```
pkill qark
```

(I didn't try this, but you can give it a try.)

**Edit:**
According to the added comments to this answer, this might even be better:

```
qark --java $f & pid=$!
sleep 5
kill $pid
```

Comment: Unless qark is spawning additional background processes that need cleaning, it's better practice to store the PID of each qark application and manage them with that than using pkill.

Comment: @tjm3772: while writing my answer, I was thinking exactly the same thing ... but do you know how to retrieve the PID of the `qark` process while starting it?

Comment: Use $! after spawning:

qark --java $f & pid=$! #(or pids+=( $! ) if you want to keep a list of them)

Then you can kill $pid if necessary.

Comment: @tjm3772: you have a point. I've adapted my answer accordingly.